# Combining php with ajax

Tags: php, ajax, echo

I would like to know if I can get the value of a "select" with id "cuadro" and put it in an echo, like that:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  url : 'plupload/examples/upload.php?<?php echo 'valor='.$?>$('#cuadro').val()<?php; ?>'
```

For the moment, the server sends me error but I do not know if I have made some syntax mistakes or it is just impossible to be done like this.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: this won't be replacing with the php variable and value..

Comment: try `url : 'plupload/examples/upload.php?valor='+$('#cuadro').val()`

Comment: Have a look at [some jQuery AJAX basics, with PHP](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html)

Comment: Thank you all, but it is not working

Answer (score 0):

Please use it like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    url : "plupload/examples/upload.php?valor="+jQuery('#cuadro').find(":selected").text();  
</script>
```

Comment: Why should the OP "use it like this"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.